# Auto suggest Textbox with multiple select features using dojo

Tags: javascript, java, dojo

I want to create an auto complete text box with multiple select features in Dojo.
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What did you tried so far? Please edit your question!

Comment: Share what you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Give the [filtering select](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/FilteringSelect.html) a try. It does auto complete and gives you a list to choose from.